# Rails6.1 paper trail gem class load issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

we have migrated from paper_trail 12.0.0 from  11.1.0 Rails version is 6.1.4. We are seeing an issue. I could not find any specific change either in rails6.1 or paper_trail change doc. Any help is appreciated.

we have defined class like this

```
class PaperTrail::Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
  belongs_to :whodidit, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'whodunnit'
  belongs_to :emp_info
end
```

when in the console try to do get user detail "whodidit" or "emp_info" we are seeing error

```
irb(main):003:0>  PaperTrail::Version.last
 PaperTrail::Version Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" ORDER BY "versions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<PaperTrail::Version id: 14987424, item_type: "......", item_id: "...", event: "create", whodunnit: "f6aa8e8c-9a39-4e8a-81e6-a20acbbc4923",  emp_info_id: "a9de8761-98a1-491f-a6b2-80a03a143d5a",........>


irb(main):004:0>  PaperTrail::Version.last.whodidit 
 PaperTrail::Version Load (14.3ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" ORDER BY "versions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
       1: from (irb):4
NoMethodError (undefined method `whodidit' for #<PaperTrail::Version:0x00007f83100362f0>)
Did you mean?  whodunnit

irb(main):005:0> PaperTrail::Version.last.emp_info 
 PaperTrail::Version Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" ORDER BY "versions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
       2: from (irb):5
       1: from (irb):5:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `emp_info' for #<PaperTrail::Version:0x00007f83100aaad8>)
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your `autoload` configuration. I suspect that your file is not `load`ed. You can confirm this hypothesis with a `puts`.